# .htacess files are not visible in Red Hat Linux Server V6.1

Tags: linux, .htaccess, visibility

.htacess files not visible in Red Hat Linux Server V6.1

Is there any option to make it visible. (Similar to "**show hidden files**" in windows)

As I'm totally new to Linux any guidance/suggestions will be highly helpful.

**PS: Not only .htaccess files. All files starting with "." are not displaying.**

Comment: On terminal you can use `ls -la`. This means to list all files, yes even hidden one. Files starting with `.` are hidden files in Linux, hidden by default.

Comment: Down voted because no effort was shown by you

Comment: @@timemachine: I didn't post the question directly over here. I've gave my best in searching on the net. I didn't find anything that is relevant. Even I've searched in stackoverflow too. No question is relevant to what I've asked now. That's why I've posted here. And, this is not a question where I can show code samples or similar to that to prove that I tried. Hope you understand.

Comment: Look i just did write `how to show hidden files in linux` in google, I found a lot of results. See the first one

Comment: @@timemachine: Thanks for your info. But, I've tried that and FYI .htaccess file is not hidden. It's not visible. I believe there is a difference between hidden and visible.

Comment: Read this `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory` . It says all files starting with `.` are hidden.

Comment: @@timemachine: Many Thanks for your support. Please post your comment as answer. Will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux everything that start with a `.` is hidden.

So to access that...

In terminal use `ls -la`

```
amit@tapas:~/temp/time$ ls
amit@tapas:~/temp/time$ touch .somefile
amit@tapas:~/temp/time$ touch anotherfile
amit@tapas:~/temp/time$ ls
anotherfile
amit@tapas:~/temp/time$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 amit amit 4096 May 13 18:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 amit amit 4096 May  7 18:05 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 amit amit    0 May 13 18:14 anotherfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 amit amit    0 May 13 18:14 .somefile
amit@tapas:~/temp/time$
```

In GUI like nautilus,you can hit `cntrl + h` to show hidden files